# All values between min and max

Tags: r

Suppose I know the min and max id, what I need is to have all ids between the min and max ones. Suppose `id<-c(1:20)` now min=1 and max=20 which function in R show the all values between these two numbers?

Comment: Maybe `id[ id >= 1 & id <= 20 ]` ?

Comment: in this special case `intersect(head(x,-1), tail(x,-1))` would work as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sets algebra:

```
id <- c(1:20)
setdiff(id, range(id))
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Also you can do:

```
id[!(id %in% range(id))]
```

or:

```
id[!(id %in% c(max(id), min(id)))]
```